# Can we give link to a sage worksheet in beamer presentation

Tags: hyperlink, sage, beamer

I would like to know whether there is a way to call a sage worksheet while presentation by giving a hyperlinking added in the presentation.
Answers are highly appreciated..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, in principle you could add any link to a Beamer presentation, right?  So for instance you could link to an [nbviewer instance](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/sagepad.org/pub/sage-test.ipynb) of a Sage Jupyter notebook.  (This link worked as of my posting it, no guarantees for how long it persists.)

However, there are also other options.  [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com) supports making worksheets publicly viewable, and you could link to those.  Some of those might even support interactive stuff.

A third answer to your question (depending upon what your actual question is) would be to use Sage to compute in your beamer, using [SageTeX](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html).  I do this a lot (not so much in beamer).

I hope one of these is along the lines of what you mean, good luck.